# C# Excel file import to GridView causes OleDB Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, oledb

I got an error about OleDB. I just want my excel file import to GridView.

Here is my code.

```
string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\a.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);

string strSQL = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(ds);

GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I build project there is no error, but when I run this project, I got an error like this:

> System.ArgumentException:Format of the
> initialization string does not conform
> to specification starting at index 47.
>
> Line 21:             string connstr =
> "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data
> Source=C:\a.xls;Extended
> Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
> Line 22:  Line 23:
> OleDbConnection conn = new
> OleDbConnection(connstr);

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\ is a special char in [c# string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx).
To specify paths in a string in c# either use escaping:

```
string path = "C:\\myFolder\\myfile.xls";
```

or use verbatim strings:

```
string path =@"C:\myfolder\myfile.xls";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string connstr needs double quotes for the Extended Properties values. e.g.:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PrmPathExcelFile + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text""");
```